# Magit: change color of filename in diffs

Tags: emacs, magit

I find it a little troublesome to distinguish filenames in Magits diffs. I would ideally like to have these in orange, so I can quickly identify where changes for a file begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize the `magit-diff-file-heading` face - do `M-x customize-face` and paste `magit-diff-file-heading` as name.  In the dialog, select "Show all attributes", and customize it, for example, change `Foreground` to Orange

Comment: You improved my quality of life by at least 6%. Thanks!